# Appending DB records into Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am attempting to append DB records retrieved into buttons which I can click on to go to the next page.

```
 function mywall(){
        $("#wallcontentset").empty();
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = serverURL() + "/category.php";

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          mywallresult(xmlhttp.responseText);
          };
         }

         xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function mywallresult(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        $("#wallcontentset").empty();
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

         var a = document.createElement("a");
         a.setAttribute("href", "#");            
         a.setAttribute("onclick","listitembycategory.html?categoryid=" + arr[i].categoryid);                 
         a.setAttribute("class","ui-btn");          
         a.innerHTML = arr[i].categoryname.toString();
         $("#wallcontentset").append(a);

        }

    }
```

The above are the set of functions that I had coded and placed in the script. The function mywall() is working fine, it retrieves every record in my database.
However I had some issues with the function mywallresult().

It creates a button for every record retrieved, however the button does not link to the next page when clicked. I couldn't identify what's wrong with my a.setAttribute.

Anyone could help me out please?

Comment: onclick need to have javascript code not the url.

Comment: where is definition of mywallresult() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to merely replace this:

```
 a.setAttribute("href", "#");            
 a.setAttribute("onclick","listitembycategory.html?categoryid=" + arr[i].categoryid);
```

by this:

```
a.setAttribute("href", "listitembycategory.html?categoryid=" + arr[i].categoryid);
```

Comment: Hi the problem is solved! I am able to go to the next page successfully! Works like magic! Many thanks!

Comment: @Dominic Gkad ti help. So might you consider accepting my answer? TIA